# Drupal Content Type issue

Tags: drupal, content-type

I am trying to edit content type but the same page is loading again when I hit "save content type".

It is Drupal 6.2 Multisite installation.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the changes you are making are getting saved. If they are getting saved then it might be a problem due to the path redirect. Check if the module is enabled and see if there is an entry for the particular path.

Comment: No, The changes are not saving. What is the module for content type?